# something is wrong with my query... no data is coming out

Tags: php, mysql

where is says #get this to working is where it does not out anything.. i am echoing the $where and it looks like all the data is there but nothing..

```
$zoom = '4';

$sql1 = "SELECT MIN(xcoord) AS min_x, MAX(xcoord) AS max_x, MIN(ycoord) AS min_y, MAX(ycoord) as max_y FROM adlplanet";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);      
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

# Create the extremes
$x_max = $row1['max_x'];
$x_min = $row1['min_x'];
$y_max = $row1['max_y'];
$y_min = $row1['min_y'];


# Calculate the size of the map based on the inputs from the user
$x_range = 800;
$y_range = 600;

$x_center = $x_max - $x_min - $x_range;
$y_center = $y_max - $y_min - $y_range;

$jump = 30;

#get this to working
$xlim = "(xcoord * $zoom) - $x_min - ($x_offset * $zoom) - ($x_center / 2)";
$ylim = "$y_max - (ycoord * $zoom) + ($y_offset * $zoom) - ($y_center / 2)";
$where  = "($xlim > 0) AND ($xlim < $x_range) AND ($ylim > 0) AND ($ylim < $y_range)";

echo $where;

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM adlPlanet where $where";
$result2 = mysql_db_query($sql2);
#$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
    echo $row2['PlanetKey'];
    echo '<br><br>  ';
}
```

Comment: Test it : `$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error())` to see that query run or not ?

Comment: Please also post table creation script (for adlPlanet) and sample data. Echoing "$sql2" and showing the query as it runs against the database would also be helpful.

Comment: also change `$result2 = mysql_db_query($sql2);` to `$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or exit(mysql_query());`

Comment: ok this is what came out

Comment: SELECT * FROM adlPlanet where ((xcoord * 4) - -605.3200 - ( * 4) - (491.45 / 2) > 0) AND ((xcoord * 4) - -605.3200 - ( * 4) - (491.45 / 2) < 800) AND (768.0000 - (ycoord * 4) + ( * 4) - (693 / 2) > 0) AND (768.0000 - (ycoord * 4) + ( * 4) - (693 / 2) < 600)

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* 4) - (491.45 / 2) > 0) AND ((xcoord * 4) - -605.3200 - ( * 4) - (491.45 / 2) <' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

`( * 4)` could not work.. check that `$x_offset` and `$y_offset` are set

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem here :

```
((xcoord * 4) - -605.3200
```

change to it :

```
$xlim = "(`xcoord` * $zoom) - ( $x_min ) 
        - ( $x_offset * $zoom ) - ( $x_center / 2 )";
$ylim = "$y_max - (`ycoord` * $zoom) + ($y_offset * $zoom) - ($y_center / 2)";
$where  = "($xlim > 0) AND ($xlim < $x_range) 
           AND ($ylim > 0) AND ($ylim < $y_range)";
```